# Camera feed sent through TCP socket gets stuck sometimes

Tags: python, sockets, tcp, raspberry-pi

I am getting the camera feed from a camera on a Raspberry PI to the computer using a TCP socket to use it for openCV. It works well with minimal delay. However, sometimes the frame gets stuck(freeze) and after a while the feed gets back or the openCV window crashes. I have looked everywhere and tried multiple things, but I just don't know what is causing it.

Server (PC):

```
import socket
import struct
import numpy as np
import cv2

host = "192.168.0.12"
portCar = 8010

# Camera socket
camS = socket.socket()
camS.bind((host, portCar))

camS.setsockopt(socket.IPPROTO_TCP, socket.TCP_NODELAY, 1)

# Listen for camera
camS.listen(0)
print("Waiting for camera connection...")

camCon = camS.accept()[0]
camFile = camCon.makefile("rb")
print("Connection made with camera")

camS.settimeout(0.00001)

numOfBytes = struct.calcsize("<L")

try:
    while(True):
        camS.setblocking(False)

        imageLength = struct.unpack("<L", camFile.read(numOfBytes))[0]    

        if imageLength == 0:
            break

        nparr = np.frombuffer(camFile.read(imageLength), np.uint8)
        frame = cv2.imdecode(nparr, cv2.IMREAD_COLOR)

        cv2.imshow('RC Car Video stream', frame)

        if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
            break

finally:
    camFile.close()
    camS.close()
    cv2.destroyAllWindows()
    print("Server - Camera connection closed")
```

Client (PI):

```
import io
import socket
import struct
import time
import picamera

client_socket = socket.socket()
client_socket.connect(('192.168.0.12', 8010))

client_socket.setsockopt(socket.IPPROTO_TCP, socket.TCP_NODELAY, 1)

connection = client_socket.makefile('wb')

class SplitFrames(object):
    def __init__(self, connection):
        self.connection = connection
        self.stream = io.BytesIO()

    def write(self, buf):
        if buf.startswith(b'\xff\xd8'):
            size = self.stream.tell()
            if size > 0:
                self.connection.write(struct.pack('<L', size))
                self.connection.flush()
                self.stream.seek(0)
                self.connection.write(self.stream.read(size))
                self.stream.seek(0)

        self.stream.write(buf)


try:
    output = SplitFrames(connection)
    with picamera.PiCamera(resolution='VGA', framerate=30) as camera:
        time.sleep(2)
        camera.rotation = 180
        camera.start_recording(output, format='mjpeg')
        camera.wait_recording(2000)
        camera.stop_recording()
        # Write the terminating 0-length to the connection to let the
        # server know we're done
        connection.write(struct.pack('<L', 0))
finally:
    connection.close()
    client_socket.close()
    print("Client - Connection closed")
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Linux isn’t a real-time operating system, and operaing from SD card is quite likely to cause delays - so maybe Pi just isn’t able to smoothly stream video without more buffering - maybe some diagnosis would be needed - have you tried your code using a dummy data source instead of the camera, have you tried adding buffering?

Comment: @barny No I haven not added buffering, I will try that.